# "Not marked as serialized" error while the class was actually marked as Serialized with annotations

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have the following action methods in my controller. I have a multipage wizard scenario here. Now when I click next I get this "....type not marked as serialized" error message. I have seen posts related to same problem but couldn't get a solution for mine.

```
 public ActionResult startOpenJAccount()
                {
                        return View(vmJ);
                }

for this method the view is something like: 
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">


 <%using (Html.BeginForm("contReg")){ %>
    <%:Html.Serialize("vmJ", Model) %>
        
      <fieldset>
    <legend> Individual Personal Profile</legend>
       <table class="col1">

          <tr>
        <td><div class="display-label">Title</div></td>
        <td><div class="display-field"><%: Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.newMember.title) %></div></td>
        </tr> 

            <tr> 
        <td><div class="display-label">First Name</div></td>
        <td><div class="display-field"><%: Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.newMember.FirstName )%></div></td>
           </tr> <tr>
 </table> 

        <div class="command"><input type="submit" name="next" value="Next" /></div>
        <div class="command"><input type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel" /></div>
    <%}%>
 </fieldset>
```

This page posts to the following action method:

```
 public ActionResult contReg(string next, string cancel)
        {
              if (next != null)
            {
                vmJ.members.Add(vmJ.newMember);   
                vmJ.newMember = new Individual();
                return RedirectToAction("displayRegInfo");
            }
            if (cancel != null)
                return RedirectToAction("displayRegInfo");
                return RedirectToAction("Index","default");
        }
```

Which for the click of Next returns this error. The class mentioned as "not marked as serializable" is not even included in the objects involved so far, instead was used later down the line in the same controller.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your question but the last return of your action method is useless.

Comment: which class is not marked as serializable (according to your error?). Also - mJ.newMember = new Individual(); i useless as well. you are redirecting to an action, these values will all be lost on redirect unless behind the scenes newMember uses TempData which is a weird solution. Also stick to Microsoft naming conventions. It makes the code a bit easier on the eyes. For instance vmj.NewMember

Comment: Not sure if this is part of the problem, but your ending fieldset tag is outside of the using. The opening fieldset tag is inside of the using. Don't know what behavior that might cause, but I figured it was worth pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

If this is an Entity Framework object you have two issues here

1. I dont believe serializeable (it inherits from an entity object)
2. Serializing it can result in a huge object

Use the POCO templates for Entity Framework. Mark your classes as serializable in the template .tt code or include [Serializable] through a partial class named the same as your class

Comment: Guys, please don't forget this is only a snippet. My question here is that why a class annotated as [Serializable] causes error with a message "Not marked as Serializable".

Comment: if it inherits from something else (like an entity class) then it could be a parent (superclass) class causing the issue.